# Are there interesting examples of theorems proved using ‘height’ extensions?

Tags: set-theory, soft-question, forcing, large-cardinals, ultrapowers

It's well known that forcing is more than a tool for proving independence: We can prove theorems and formulate axioms in theories like $\mathsf{ZFC}$ by moving to forcing extensions (e.g. $\mathfrak{p}=\mathfrak{t}$, remarkable cardinals, Todorčević and Farah's book "Some applications of the method of forcing"). Are there nice examples of theorems/axioms that use "height" extensions (i.e. where we use "ordinals" longer than $\mathit{Ord}$ or where the resources required are strictly greater than second-order etc.) to prove some result in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ (or an extension thereof) or about the ground model? (From here on, let "height extension of $M$" denote any model $M'$ such that $\mathit{Ord}^M \in M'$).

Some uses that occur to me:

1. Uses of $\mathsf{ETR}$ in class theory (e.g. using iterated truth predicates and the connection to determinacy for class games, cf. Gitman and Hamkins "[Open Determinacy for Class Games](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01099)").
2. #-generation. This is a technical axiom to state, so I won't do so here, the core point is that we capture reflection properties of some model $M$ by taking it to be an initial segment of a model $M'$ generated by an ultrapower construction (this ultrapower, in turn, may be longer than $\mathit{Ord}^M$). See Honzik and Friedman "[On Strong Forms of Reflection in Set Theory](https://www1.cuni.cz/%7Ehonzikr/papers/reflection_revised_MLQ.pdf)" for details.
3. There are useful definable well-order longer than $\mathit{Ord}$ (e.g. the ordering on mice).

I am curious as to whether the use of such "height" extensions pops up a lot in set-theoretic practice, and whether its as useful/ubiquitous as the use of forcing in proving theorems and formulating axioms (beyond relative consistency).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is another instance, which appears in my recent paper with Bokai Yao on second-order reflection in the context of KMU with abundant urelements.

- Joel David Hamkins and Bokai Yao, [Reflection in second-order set theory with abundant urelemets bi-interprets a supercompact cardinal](http://jdh.hamkins.org/second-order-reflection-with-abundant-urelements), 2022, [arXiv:2204.09766](https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.09766).

The following theorem is an immediate consequence of the main theorem.

**Theorem.** Assume Kelley-Morse set theory with urelements KMU, with the abundant atom axiom and second-order reflection. Then there is a stationary proper class of measurable cardinals, partially supercompact cardinals, and more.

I mention the theorem because the main proof method is to undertake the unrolling construction, which produces sets at ranks higher than Ord.

[image]

Starting at lower right in the model $\langle V(A),\in,\mathcal{V}\rangle$ in which the hypothesis is satisfied, we undertake unrolling to produce the models $W$ and $\bar V$, in which there is a supercompact cardinal. In fact, it is the cardinal $\kappa=\text{Ord}^V$ that becomes supercompact in these taller models. And the supercompactness of $\kappa$ in $\bar V$ and $W$ reflects to diverse consequences in the original universe $V(A)$ and its class of pure sets $V$, such as a stationary proper class of measurable and partially supercompact cardinals, as much supercompactness as desired.

Comment: Interesting answer, and nice diagrams; out of curiosity, is there any advantage to set theories with urelements vs pure set theories? Do they ever add height in addition to width, or is the width they add ever useful for concisely proving theorems/making definitions in a way that is cumbersome with pure sets?

Comment: In our paper, we prove essentially that all of the most common urelement theories are bi-interpretable with pure set theories. For example, ZFC with ZFCU + Ord many urelements or ℝ many, KM with KMU+omega many atoms, etc. A many for any class A of pure sets. We take this to explain on structuralist grounds set theory has largely abandoned urelements. Any mathematical structure to be formed in these urelement theories is isomorphic to one in the pure set universe.

Comment: @AlecRhea Interestingly, urelements actually become rather important when one dives into the details around *weaker* set theories. Barwise's book [**Admissible sets and structures**](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/perspectives-in-logic/Admissible-Sets-and-Structures-An-Approach-to-Definability-Theory/toc/pl/1235418470) has a discussion of this at the beginning; ZFC is strong enough to elide the issues that crop up here, but sometimes (e.g. in computability theory) weaker theories (e.g. KP) are important and there urelements may play a more significantly simplifying role.

Comment: To add to Noah's comment. They're also relevant for certain metamathematical purposes. Vann McGee's result that any two universes of second-order ZFCU + ``there is a set of all urelemente'' have isomorphic pure sets depends on there not being `too many' urelements.

Comment: Urelements plays a crucial role in the "unorthodox" set theory NFU (The extension of Quine's NF, introduced by (Ronald) Jensen); Jensen showed the consistency of NFU relative to a weak fragment of ZF).  As shown by Marcel Crabbé, models of NFU that are not models of NF have an abundant number of urelements (as shown in his paper "On the set of atoms", Log. J. IGPL 8 (2000), no. 6, 751–759).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example.

The *maximality principle* in forcing is the scheme asserting of every statement $\varphi$ in the language of set theory that if there is forcing extension $V[G]$ of the set-theoretic universe $V$ for which all further forcing extensions $V[G][H]$ satisfy $\varphi$, then $\varphi$ was already true in the original universe $V$.

The principle is naturally expressed in modal terms, using the forcing interpretation of the modal operators, by the S5 axiom $\Diamond\Box\varphi\to\varphi$.

I introduced this forcing modality in my paper:

- *Hamkins, Joel David*, [**A simple maximality principle.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1052669062), J. Symb. Log. 68, No. 2, 527-550 (2003). [ZBL1056.03028](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1056.03028).

And I also gave several consistency proofs of the maximality principle, one of which is relevant for your question. Namely, if there is a *fully correct* cardinal $\delta$, which means that the scheme $V_\delta\prec V$ holds, then there is a forcing extension of the universe $V[G]$ in which the maximality principle holds. Basically, one lines up all the statements $\varphi_0$, $\varphi_1,\dots$, and then at each stage you ask whether $\varphi_n$ is forceably necessary over $V_\delta$, and if so, you add a forcing factor to achieve this. This defines a finite-support iteration, which will be a forcing extension $V[G]$ in which every instance of the MP is true.

Intuitively, one wants to carry this argument out over $V$, except that it would require us to use a truth predicate since asking whether a given statement is forceable is as hard as asking whether it is true. This is why $V_\delta\prec V$ helps us out, because we need only ask about forcing over $V_\delta$, which is a set, and so we have a truth predicate there.

The hypothesis that $V_\delta\prec V$ cannot be omitted from the proof that MP is forceable, for there are some models of ZFC that have no forcing extensions satisfying MP.

The method accommodates real parameters, if you also assume that $\delta$ is inaccessible, and the assumption $V_\delta\prec V$ is equivalent in consistency strength over ZFC to Ord being definably Mahlo. The result is a model of the boldfact maximality principle $\text{MP}(\mathbb{R})$.

The **relevance for your question** is that the hypothesis $V_\delta\prec V$ is conservative over ZFC. A simple compactness argument shows by the reflection theorem that every model $W$ of ZFC has an extension with a cardinal $\delta$ for which $W\prec V_\delta\prec V$. Thus, we have extended the model $W$ by adding $\delta$ and a lot of other ordinals on top of $\delta$, in the style of your question. Starting with any model $W$, we can find an elementary extension $V$, with taller ordinals, having a forcing extension $V[G]$ in which the maximality principle holds.

And we get a similar conservativity for $V_\delta\prec V+\delta$ inaccessible over the theory ZFC + Ord is definably Mahlo.

The maximality principle was introduced and studied before my paper (independently) by:

- *Stavi, Jonathan; Väänänen, Jouko*, Reflection principles for the continuum, Zhang, Yi (ed.), Logic and algebra. Providence, RI: American Mathematical Society (AMS). Contemp. Math. 302, 59-84 (2002). [ZBL1013.03059](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1013.03059).

Unfortunately, this paper is slightly marred by the oversight that they do not state or use the hypothesis $V_\delta\prec V$, and they suggest that the maximality principle is forceable over every model of ZFC. But this is not true, as I had mentioned. Fortunately, one can correct their arguments simply by incorporating $V_\delta\prec V$ in the style of my arguments.